# How do you compare elements of a list with a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

```
a = [[1, 3, 4],[1, 7, 9]]]
b = [1, 7, 0, 9]
```

Let's say I have a nested list of a, I want to compare the list of b to the nested list `a` and return True. Say `b` has 3 items that matches with one of the lists in `a`, that would be True. How do I do this?

the prompt was to create a tic tac toe game. List a has all the winning combinations, while list b are all the player input. If input is contains 1, 7, and 9 (as in list b), then the combination is part of the winning combinations (in list a). However, player input could include more than 3 numbers and not in the combination order in list a.

I tried the below:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4],[1,7,9]]
b = [1, 7, 0, 9]
set(a).issubset(b)
```

But clearly it did not work.

Comment: What's the logic here, why would this comparison return true?

Comment: @deceze I think she is looking for a function that returns True, if an item from list b contains in one of the lists in list a. I just wanted to post a solution, but the question is closed.

Comment: @Aterus Well, let's wait for OP to actually clarify, before we write speculative code.

Answer (score 2):

Using **super**set:

```py
a = [[1, 3, 4], [1, 7, 9]]
b = [1, 7, 0, 9]

print(any(map(set(b).issuperset, a)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3gxIVbBWiow11FIx1FExidRRATHMdBcvYWK4kkBSEawAS4eIqKMrMK9FIzKvUyE0s0ChOLdFI0tTLLC4uLUgtAvJ0FBI1NTUhJkMtgFkEAA)

Answer (score 1):

You want to check for each individual list in `a` whether it's a subset of `b`. If that's the case for any one, the result is true:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [1, 7, 9]]
b = [1, 7, 0, 9]

b = set(b)
print(any(set(i) <= b for i in a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Building from what you have tried, I think you want to do the following:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4],[1,7,9]]
b = [1, 7, 0, 9]

for item in a:
    if set(item).issubset(b):
        print(item, 'is subset of', b)
```

or in general, if you want to check if any item of `a` is a subset of `b`:

```
any(set(item).issubset(b) for item in a)
```

Comment: Remove the `[]` from your `any`; that requires the entire list to be evaluated first. Without the `[]`, it's a generator expression and `any` can stop as soon as it finds a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the all of the contents of a sublist of `a` are in `b`, you can use a `set` and check the difference.

```
compare = [[1, 3, 4],[1, 7, 9]]
moves   = [1, 7, 0, 9]

def check(a:list[list], b:list) -> bool:
    y = set(b)
    return any(not (x-y) for x in map(set, a))
    
print(check(compare, moves))
```

Comment: A subset check would be a lot more straight forward here than `not x - y`. Also, this could be reduced to an `any()` with iterator expression.

Comment: @deceze - I am unsure what you mean by a subset check. Isn't that exactly what this is? Also, `any` would require looping over the entire dataset, whereas this will return early if it can.

Comment: See my answer. A subset check explicitly tells you if one set is a subset of another; what you're doing is form a third set and evaluate its booleaness. Same result, but more complicated. And no, `any` also short circuits.

Comment: @deceze - I understand now. Unfortunately, there are now 2 subset answers so, I will leave mine as an alternative, even if it isn't necessarily the most efficient.

Comment: @deceze If you want to avoid a third set, you might also want to avoid a second:-)